# merge group by data into single list or dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Hello I am new to python and not sure how to achieve.

| ID | ENTITY_NAME | ENTITY_NAME | SECTION_GROUP | DOC_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dNumber | U220059090 | GROUP 1 | 40 |
| 2 | tDate | 6-Dec-22 | GROUP 1 | 40 |
| 3 | dNumber | U220059090 | GROUP 2 | 40 |
| 4 | tDate | 6-Dec-22 | GROUP 2 | 40 |
| 5 | sCompany | bp | nan | 40 |
| 6 | dNumber | U220059090 | GROUP 1 | 45 |
| 7 | tDate | 6-Dec-22 | GROUP 1 | 45 |
| 8 | dNumber | U220059090 | GROUP 2 | 45 |
| 9 | tDate | 6-Dec-22 | GROUP 2 | 45 |
| 10 | sCompany | bp | nan | 45 |

I have applied group by to section_group column on below data and got two different result set in dataframe as below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv ('dups_check_group_v1.csv',encoding= 'unicode_escape',usecols= ['ID','ENTITY_NAME','ENTITY_VALUE','SECTION_GROUP','DOC_ID'])

mask = df['SECTION_GROUP'].isna()
rest = df[mask]

for _, g in df[~mask].groupby('SECTION_GROUP'):
    g = pd.concat([g, rest])
    print(g)
```

Result

```
ID ENTITY_NAME   ENTITY_VALUE SECTION_GROUP  DOC_ID
0   1     dNumber  U220059090(C)       GROUP 1      40
1   2       tDate       6-Dec-22       GROUP 1      40
5   6     dNumber  U220059090(C)       GROUP 1      45
6   7       tDate       6-Dec-22       GROUP 1      45
4   5    sCompany             bp           NaN      40
9  10    sCompany             bp           NaN      45

ID ENTITY_NAME   ENTITY_VALUE SECTION_GROUP  DOC_ID
2   3     dNumber  U220059090(C)       GROUP 2      40
3   4       tDate       6-Dec-22       GROUP 2      40
7   8     dNumber  U220059090(C)       GROUP 2      45
8   9       tDate       6-Dec-22       GROUP 2      45
4   5    sCompany             bp           NaN      40
9  10    sCompany             bp           NaN      45
```

I am trying to merge this two results into single result. like below. any help will be really appreciate.

```
ID ENTITY_NAME   ENTITY_VALUE SECTION_GROUP  DOC_ID
    0   1     dNumber  U220059090(C)       GROUP 1      40
    1   2       tDate       6-Dec-22       GROUP 1      40
    5   6     dNumber  U220059090(C)       GROUP 1      45
    6   7       tDate       6-Dec-22       GROUP 1      45
    4   5    sCompany             bp           NaN      40
    9  10    sCompany             bp           NaN      45
    2   3     dNumber  U220059090(C)       GROUP 2      40
    3   4       tDate       6-Dec-22       GROUP 2      40
    7   8     dNumber  U220059090(C)       GROUP 2      45
    8   9       tDate       6-Dec-22       GROUP 2      45
    4   5    sCompany             bp           NaN      40
    9  10    sCompany             bp           NaN      45
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) again:

```
out = pd.concat([pd.concat([g, rest]) for _, g in
                 df[~mask].groupby('SECTION_GROUP')])
```

Or rework your loop:

```
out = pd.concat([d for _, g in df[~mask].groupby('SECTION_GROUP')
                 for d in [g, rest]])
```

Output:

```
   ID ENTITY_NAME ENTITY_NAME.1 SECTION_GROUP  DOC_ID
0   1     dNumber    U220059090       GROUP 1      40
1   2       tDate      6-Dec-22       GROUP 1      40
5   6     dNumber    U220059090       GROUP 1      45
6   7       tDate      6-Dec-22       GROUP 1      45
4   5    sCompany            bp           NaN      40
9  10    sCompany            bp           NaN      45
2   3     dNumber    U220059090       GROUP 2      40
3   4       tDate      6-Dec-22       GROUP 2      40
7   8     dNumber    U220059090       GROUP 2      45
8   9       tDate      6-Dec-22       GROUP 2      45
4   5    sCompany            bp           NaN      40
9  10    sCompany            bp           NaN      45
```

Comment: could you please help me with the below question?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75606130/create-new-column-with-incremental-values/75606275#75606275

Comment: I see you already got an answer ;)

Comment: yes, but when I tried adding more data (doc_id) its not behaving as wanted.

Comment: Hi @mozway, could you please help me with this question. I am still stuck in the same issues. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75654890/how-to-merge-tuple-and-dataframe-data

Comment: @tt0206 sorry, seeing this too late, but you got two good answers ;)