# create new column with incremental values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have below result set which got populated with the following code. I require to add new Column GROUP_ID in this result.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv ('dups_check_group_v1.csv',encoding= 'unicode_escape',usecols= ['ID','ENTITY_NAME','ENTITY_VALUE','SECTION_GROUP','DOC_ID'])

mask = df['SECTION_GROUP'].isna()
rest = df[mask]

out = pd.concat([d for _, g in df[~mask].groupby('SECTION_GROUP')
                 for d in [g, rest]])
print(out.sort_values('DOC_ID'))
```

Result

```
    ID ENTITY_NAME   ENTITY_VALUE SECTION_GROUP  DOC_ID
0   1     dNumber  U220059090(C)       GROUP 1      40
1   2       tDate       6-Dec-22       GROUP 1      40
4   5    sCompany             bp           NaN      40
2   3     dNumber  U220059090(C)       GROUP 2      40
3   4       tDate       6-Dec-22       GROUP 2      40
4   5    sCompany             bp           NaN      40
5   6     dNumber  U220059090(C)       GROUP 1      42
6   7       tDate       6-Dec-22       GROUP 1      42
9  10    sCompany             bp           NaN      42
7   8     dNumber  U220059090(C)       GROUP 2      42
8   9       tDate       6-Dec-22       GROUP 2      42
9  10    sCompany             bp           NaN      42
```

what I am looking to achieve with GROUP_ID is as below. any help is really appreciate.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your existing concat statement to assign group ids dynamically

```
grps = df[~mask].groupby('SECTION_GROUP')
out = pd.concat([d.assign(GROUP_ID=i) for i, (_, g) in enumerate(grps, 1) for d in [g, rest]])
```

Comment: second GROUP_ID got reset for new DOC_ID. Is it possible to increment GROUP_ID even after DOC_ID changes? like GROUP_ID 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4 ?

Comment: I see. Its hard to tell without reproducible input dataframe. Can you check `out ['SECTION_GROUP'].isna().shift(fill_value=0).cumsum().add(1)` if this works for your usecase

Comment: tried but didn't work.. may be I am not clear on where this statement should go.

Comment: Follow this after concat in your code: `out = out.sort_values('DOC_ID')` then 
`out['GROUP_ID'] = out['SECTION_GROUP'].isna().shift(fill_value=0).cumsum().add(1)`

Comment: perfect ! this is working as expected :) thanks Shubham

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252234/discussion-between-tt0206-and-shubham-sharma).