# how to merge tuple and dataframe data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

may be my questions is too basic but I am learning python. Let me know if you need more information.

I have dataframe as below.

```
     ID     Model MVersion  dId   sGroup        eName         eValue
0    1      Main      V15   40  GROUP 1      dNumber  U220059090(C)
1    2      Main      V15   40  GROUP 1        tDate          44901
2    3      Main      V15   40  GROUP 2      dNumber  U220059090(C)
3    4      Main      V15   40  GROUP 2        tDate          44901
4    5      Main      V15   40     None     sCompany             bp
5    6      Main      V15   42  GROUP 1      dNumber  U220059090(C)
6    7      Main      V15   42  GROUP 1        tDate          44901
7    8      Main      V15   42  GROUP 2      dNumber  U220059090(C)
8    9      Main      V15   42  GROUP 2        tDate          44901
9   10      Main      V15   42     None     sCompany             bp
10  11      Main      V15   44     None       Sender         sDummy
11  12      Main      V15   44     None    TradeDate         Tdummy
12  13      Main      V15   44     None      Product         Pdummy
13  14      Main      V15   44     None       seller        seDummy
```

I needed to apply grouping on Model, MVersion, dId & sGroup columns which I have done below.

I am trying to get result as below into separate group the **None** sGroup should be part of Group1 and Group2 for each dId. some dId might have all sGroup as None. Also is that possible to add new column as Group_Id with Incremental values.

```
         ID     Model MVersion  dId   sGroup        eName         eValue  Group_Id
    0    1      Main      V15   40  GROUP 1      dNumber  U220059090(C)   1
    1    2      Main      V15   40  GROUP 1        tDate          44901   1
    4    5      Main      V15   40     None     sCompany             bp   1

         ID     Model MVersion  dId   sGroup        eName         eValue  Group_Id
    2    3      Main      V15   40  GROUP 2      dNumber  U220059090(C)   2
    3    4      Main      V15   40  GROUP 2        tDate          44901   2
    4    5      Main      V15   40     None     sCompany             bp   2


        ID     Model MVersion  dId   sGroup        eName         eValue   Group_Id
    5    6      Main      V15   42  GROUP 1      dNumber  U220059090(C)   3
    6    7      Main      V15   42  GROUP 1        tDate          44901   3
    9   10      Main      V15   42     None     sCompany             bp   3

        ID     Model MVersion  dId   sGroup        eName         eValue   Group_Id
    7    8      Main      V15   42  GROUP 2      dNumber  U220059090(C)   4
    8    9      Main      V15   42  GROUP 2        tDate          44901   4
    9   10      Main      V15   42     None     sCompany             bp   4

        ID     Model MVersion  dId   sGroup        eName         eValue   Group_Id
    10  11      Main      V15   44     None       Sender         sDummy   5
    11  12      Main      V15   44     None    TradeDate         Tdummy   5
    12  13      Main      V15   44     None      Product         Pdummy   5
    13  14      Main      V15   44     None       seller        seDummy   5
```

what I have tried is to filtered out all None to one dataframe and applied grouping on Model, MVersion, dId and SGroup. I am not sure how can I combined these two result into one. I don't know what is correct and efficient way to do this. any help is really appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
[1,'Main','V15',      40,'GROUP 1','dNumber','U220059090(C)'],
[2,'Main','V15',      40,'GROUP 1','tDate','44901'],
[3,'Main','V15',      40,'GROUP 2','dNumber','U220059090(C)'],
[4,'Main','V15',      40,'GROUP 2','tDate','44901'],
[5,'Main','V15',      40,None, 'sCompany','bp'],
[6,'Main','V15',      42,'GROUP 1','dNumber','U220059090(C)'],
[7,'Main','V15',      42,'GROUP 1','tDate','44901'],
[8,'Main','V15',      42,'GROUP 2','dNumber','U220059090(C)'],
[9,'Main','V15',      42,'GROUP 2','tDate','44901'],
[10,'Main','V15',     42,None,'sCompany','bp'],
[11,'Main','V15',     44,None,'Sender','sDummy'],
[12,'Main','V15',     44,None,'TradeDate','Tdummy'],
[13,'Main','V15',     44,None,'Product','Pdummy'],
[14,'Main','V15',     44,None,'seller','seDummy'],
[15,'Delivery','V15', 40,None,'delIncoTerm','FIP'],
[16,'Delivery','V15', 40,None,'delWindow','44562'],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ID','Model','MVersion','dId','sGroup','eName','eValue'])
print(df)
print('\n')

nullSectionGroup = df[df['sGroup'].isnull()]
print('null sGroup')
print('----------------')
print(nullSectionGroup)
print('\n')

grpModel = df.groupby('Model') # 1) group by Model
for model in grpModel:
    grpModelVersion = model[1].groupby('MVersion') # 2) group by MVersion
    for modelVersion in grpModelVersion:
        grpDocId = modelVersion[1].groupby('dId') # 3) group by dId
        for docId in grpDocId:
            #print('docId', docId)
            grpSG = docId[1].groupby('sGroup') # 4) group by sGroup
            
            for x in grpSG:
                #variable declarition
                model = x[1].Model.iloc[0]
                modelVersion = x[1].MVersion.iloc[0]
                docId = x[1].dId.iloc[0]
                sectionGroup  = x[1].sGroup.iloc[0]
                                
                #filtering dataframe of null section group based on x[1] values
                #print('****model :', model, '**mVersion :', mVersion, '**Doc_Id :', dId, '**sGroup :', sGroup)
                filtered_value = nullSectionGroup.loc[(nullSectionGroup['Model']==model)&(nullSectionGroup['MVersion']==modelVersion)&(nullSectionGroup['dId']==docId)]
                print('filtered_value => pandas.core.frame.DataFrame')
                print(filtered_value)
                print('grouped values => tuple')
                print(x)
                print('\n')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
# conver the `None` string to actual None (if necessary)
df.loc[df['sGroup'].eq('None'), 'sGroup'] = None

grp_num = 1
for _, g1 in df.groupby(['Model', 'MVersion', 'dId']):
    mask = g1['sGroup'].isna()

    if mask.all():
        g1['Group_Id'] = grp_num
        grp_num += 1
        print(g1)
        print()
    else:
        for _, g2 in g1[~mask].groupby('sGroup'):
            g2 = pd.concat([g2, g1[mask]])
            g2['Group_Id'] = grp_num
            grp_num += 1
            print(g2)
            print()
```

Prints:

```
   ID Model MVersion  dId   sGroup     eName         eValue  Group_Id
0   1  Main      V15   40  GROUP 1   dNumber  U220059090(C)         1
1   2  Main      V15   40  GROUP 1     tDate          44901         1
4   5  Main      V15   40     None  sCompany             bp         1

   ID Model MVersion  dId   sGroup     eName         eValue  Group_Id
2   3  Main      V15   40  GROUP 2   dNumber  U220059090(C)         2
3   4  Main      V15   40  GROUP 2     tDate          44901         2
4   5  Main      V15   40     None  sCompany             bp         2

   ID Model MVersion  dId   sGroup     eName         eValue  Group_Id
5   6  Main      V15   42  GROUP 1   dNumber  U220059090(C)         3
6   7  Main      V15   42  GROUP 1     tDate          44901         3
9  10  Main      V15   42     None  sCompany             bp         3

   ID Model MVersion  dId   sGroup     eName         eValue  Group_Id
7   8  Main      V15   42  GROUP 2   dNumber  U220059090(C)         4
8   9  Main      V15   42  GROUP 2     tDate          44901         4
9  10  Main      V15   42     None  sCompany             bp         4

    ID Model MVersion  dId sGroup      eName   eValue  Group_Id
10  11  Main      V15   44   None     Sender   sDummy         5
11  12  Main      V15   44   None  TradeDate   Tdummy         5
12  13  Main      V15   44   None    Product   Pdummy         5
13  14  Main      V15   44   None     seller  seDummy         5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
cols = ['Model', 'MVersion', 'dId']
m = df['sGroup'].isnull()

# Set multiple groups for all None values
xgrp = (df['sGroup'].fillna(df.groupby(cols)['sGroup']
                              .transform(lambda x: ','.join(set(x.dropna())))
                    .str.split(',')))

# Group by usual columns + xgrp
dfs = [subdf.drop(columns='xgrp').assign(Group_Id=gid) 
           for gid, (_, subdf) in enumerate(df.assign(xgrp=xgrp).explode('xgrp')
                                              .groupby(cols + ['xgrp'], sort=False))]
```

Output:

```
>>> dfs[0]
   ID Model MVersion  dId   sGroup     eName         eValue  Group_Id
0   1  Main      V15   40  GROUP 1   dNumber  U220059090(C)         0
1   2  Main      V15   40  GROUP 1     tDate          44901         0
4   5  Main      V15   40     None  sCompany             bp         0

>>> dfs[1]
   ID Model MVersion  dId   sGroup     eName         eValue  Group_Id
2   3  Main      V15   40  GROUP 2   dNumber  U220059090(C)         1
3   4  Main      V15   40  GROUP 2     tDate          44901         1
4   5  Main      V15   40     None  sCompany             bp         1

>>> dfs[2]
   ID Model MVersion  dId   sGroup     eName         eValue  Group_Id
5   6  Main      V15   42  GROUP 1   dNumber  U220059090(C)         2
6   7  Main      V15   42  GROUP 1     tDate          44901         2
9  10  Main      V15   42     None  sCompany             bp         2

>>> dfs[3]
   ID Model MVersion  dId   sGroup     eName         eValue  Group_Id
7   8  Main      V15   42  GROUP 2   dNumber  U220059090(C)         3
8   9  Main      V15   42  GROUP 2     tDate          44901         3
9  10  Main      V15   42     None  sCompany             bp         3

>>> dfs[4]
    ID Model MVersion  dId sGroup      eName   eValue  Group_Id
10  11  Main      V15   44   None     Sender   sDummy         4
11  12  Main      V15   44   None  TradeDate   Tdummy         4
12  13  Main      V15   44   None    Product   Pdummy         4
13  14  Main      V15   44   None     seller  seDummy         4

>>> dfs[5]
    ID     Model MVersion  dId sGroup        eName eValue  Group_Id
14  15  Delivery      V15   40   None  delIncoTerm    FIP         5
15  16  Delivery      V15   40   None    delWindow  44562         5
```